# Creating Directory Dynamically by using Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, batch

I have a question over here that I wish to achieve.

Let's say the scenario looks like this:

In BuildFolder there are these files:

Z:\BuildFolder\Build#170
Z:\BuildFolder\Build#171
Z:\BuildFolder\Build#172
Z:\BuildFolder\Build#173
Z:\BuildFolder\Build#174
Z:\BuildFolder\Changelog
Z:\BuildFolder\Misc

What I want to achieve in the batch file are:

1. Looping the directory and get only the one starting with Build#xxx. I have achieved this one by using

   ```
   for /D %%s in (.\Build#*) do @echo %%s
   ```
2. How to get the last index of the Build Folder like knowing the next directory that's going to be created is Build#175 ?

Comment: Not an answer ... but really, these kind of things are much more easily and robustly achieved using more featurefull languages such as PowerShell or Node.JS (JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably Add a line in the Loop itself to predict what the next value of index might be (assuming it always increments by 1).
I've included the snippet of the code below

Add the following line at the very beginning of the script

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Then modify the loop as given below. This is assuming the folder will always be named as **Build#**. Hence it skips the first 6 characters to get the index value. Finally print the fetched value +1. The last fetched value will be the highest index

```
FOR /D %%s in (".\Build#*") do (
set name=%%~ns
set /a index=!name:~6!
)
set /a nextindex=!index!+1
ECHO next folder is %nextindex%
pause
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you think it helped and select it (the green tick mark) :)

Answer (score 0):

Powershell (as Julian Knight suggested):

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp> Get-ChildItem -Filter 'Build#*'


    Directory: C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        30.03.2015     14:19            Build#170
d----        30.03.2015     14:19            Build#171
d----        30.03.2015     14:19            Build#172
d----        30.03.2015     14:19            Build#173
d----        30.03.2015     14:19            Build#174


PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp> Get-ChildItem -Filter 'Build#*' | select -Last 1


    Directory: C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        30.03.2015     14:19            Build#174


PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp> Get-ChildItem -Filter 'Build#*' | select -Last 1 | format-list *


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\user\Desktop
                    \tmp\Build#174
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\user\Desktop
                    \tmp
PSChildName       : Build#174
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
BaseName          : Build#174
Mode              : d----
Name              : Build#174
Parent            : tmp
Exists            : True
Root              : C:\
FullName          : C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp\Build#174
Extension         :
CreationTime      : 30.03.2015 14:19:36
CreationTimeUtc   : 30.03.2015 12:19:36
LastAccessTime    : 30.03.2015 14:19:36
LastAccessTimeUtc : 30.03.2015 12:19:36
LastWriteTime     : 30.03.2015 14:19:36
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 30.03.2015 12:19:36
Attributes        : Directory



PS C:\Users\xnem\Desktop\tmp>
```